# Refactor in Visual Studio Express 2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

It's funny I have to ask this but I can't figure it out. I'm used to coding Java in Eclipse where you have the shortcut Alt + Shift + R to refactor/rename a variable. Now I'm learning C++ and thought I should use Visual Studio.

What's the darn shortcut in VS2010 Express? C + . or Alt + Shift + F10 are not doing anything.

Kind regards,
Frustrated coder

EDIT: Simply using the 'quick find and rename' thing is not useful since I made the 'mistake' of naming some variables with single letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio versions before 2015 (in preview now) doesn't have support for refactoring C++ code at all. For VS 2013 there is an extension that adds the refactor/rename option for C++.

Since you're using the free Express edition maybe upgrading to the free 2013 <strike>Express</strike> [Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) edition could work? (Apparently the Express editions doesn't allow add-ins, but the Community ed. does).

[Visual C++ Refactoring extension for VS2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/164904b2-3b47-417f-9b6b-fdd35757d194).

About the upcoming features: [All about C++ Refactoring in Visual Studio 2015 Preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/14/all-about-c-refactoring-in-visual-studio-2015-preview.aspx)

Comment: I'm quite surprised there isn't a refactoring option; seems like something quite useful that should be there. In any case, thank you for the answer! Guess I'll just get VS2013, though I'm leaving the question open, perhaps someone found another way to do it in VS2010 that would save me the hassle of installing other stuff.

Comment: @Dimebag Upgrading is most likely the best option (note that you should get the community edition though) as it gives you access to better tools and better support for modern C++. There are some commercial tools for refactoring available like Visual Assist X and CodeRush but I haven't used either and am not sure if they support 2010.